# Loading Tensorflow 2.6 protocol buffers into Java 8

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, tensorflow2

I have been able to successfully build a transformer network in Tensorflow (v 2.6), produce a  protocol buffer (.pb) in python for that model, and then read that back into **python** for execution.

But when I try to read the .pb into **Java 8**, I get the statement "While parsing a protocol message, the input ended unexpectedly in the middle of the field."

Not quite sure what this could mean. Are there any examples of non-Keras TF 2.x models being loaded into Java that I could study?

For reference, I am essentially trying to load a .pb such as that being built on the Tensorflow transformer tutorial at https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/transformer.

Thanks for any thoughts on this!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.